# How to arbitrarily select value of limit tags based on the width of my autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If the width of Autocomplete is 600 px and the tags cover all 600 then the remaining selected options should be rendered as +n. [Autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwZ6b.png)
This should render +1 instead of showing the 4th option and on selecting the filter field all 4 should show up the way it is now. I need to use MUI to do this I am using a custom autocomplete with multi-list-tags as well as free solo.

```
<Autocomplete
      multiple
      limitTags={1}
      id='multiple-limit-tags'
      options={dropDownOptions.map((option) => option.title)}
      value={value}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setValue([...newValue]);
      }}
      onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        setInputValue(newInputValue);
      }}
      freeSolo
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label='Filters' />
      )}
      sx={{ width: availableWidth }}
    />
```